# Cannot edit question? Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code

Tags: support, markdown

I was trying to edit this [Experiences on free and low-cost hosting for play framework applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974265/experiences-on-free-and-low-cost-hosting-for-play-framework-applications)

I wanted to fix the formatting, so that it looks like this:
(Actually it would contain more links, but I'm not allowed to post more than two links here).

> I'd like to know your experience finding a host for play applications on free or low-cost servers.
>
> So far now I found the following options:
>
> - [Playapps](http://www.playapps.net/)
>
>   A cloud hosting solution by zenexity, the company behind play framework
>     [Module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/playapps-1.4/home)
>     [Princing][3]
> - [Google Application Engine][4]
>
>   [Module][5]
>     Cons: You can't use mysql, you should not use JPA. Instead of JPA it is  advised to use [siena][6].
>     [Nice example][7]
> - [Cloudbees][8]
>
>   [Module][9]
>     [Pricing][10]
>     [Floss][11]
>     [Tutorial][12]
> - [dotCloud][13]
>
>   [Module][14]
>     [Princing][15] (there's a free plan with 10MB db)
>     [Floss][16]
>
>   (updated)
> - [AWS - Amazon Web Services][17]
>
>   [Pricing][18]
>     [More pricing][19]
>     [Sample][20]
>     [Another sample][21]
> - [Heroku for play!][22]
>
>   [Princing][23] (Seems like you get 1 web dyno and 5mb postresql dabate for free)
>     [Sample][24]
>
> Do you have any experience with one of these?
>
> Any other option you know?

But I got an error message

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Why is that? The question does not contain any code.

Comment: (OT to this question, but I just posted a vote to close on your SO post. "List of stuff" questions are not a good fit for a Q&A site.)

Comment: @Mat Well, I hesitated before I started to edit, because I thought it might get closed, but then I decided to edit it anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "poll questions" as questions. Invest some time in the site and you will see what questions are appropriate to ask. Your question should be closed as "Not Constructive".

Comment: @0A0D I was in the impression that this is a bug: I edit a question containing _no code_, but it got rejected saying it _contains unformatted code_. Maybe I did something wrong when I was editing (as it worked for Mat) but still then the error message is misleading. Are questions about bugs / bug reports inappropriate to ask on meta?

Comment: @0A0D Oh, I just realized you are talking about the question I was trying to edit (it was not asked by me, that's why I was confused). Ignore my last comment then.

Comment: It's not your fault, apparently multiple people just assumed the question was yours without actually looking at it. This is the right place for bug reports (even though this just got retagged as support for some reason)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get a warning with the edit I just did. The formatting is as follows:

`- Title`
`<blank line>`
`______Stuff__`
`______MoreStuff__`
`______OtherStuff`

Four spaces before the stuff in the list, two spaces at end of line for all but the last stuff (in order not to have too much vertical space between the items like you'd get with an empty line between each - I'm guessing that is what triggered the "code-look-alike" filter if you had empty lines alternating with code-indented lines).

Renders as:

- Title

  Stuff
  MoreStuff
  OtherStuff

And if you want code in there (as you should on SO, posts without code are sad):

- Title

  Stuff

  ```
  <just indent="four more">to get code in the list</just>
  ```

  OtherStuff